# PHP and MYSQL to Create table in HTML with conditional statement

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

i have table tb_satker

```
kode_propinsi | nama_satker  |  kode_satker
500           | A            |  1
500           | B            |  2
500           | C            |  3
500           | D            |  4
```

also table tb_upload

```
kode_propinsi | kode_satker  |  month
500           | A            |  1
500           | A            |  2
500           | B            |  3
```

I want to create php and mysql code to generate table like this

```
No | UPT | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | Mei | Jun | Jul | Ags | Sep | Okt | Nov | Des
1  | A   | 1   | 2   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   |  0  | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0
2  | B   | 0   | 0   | 3   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   |  0  | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0
3  | C   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   |  0  | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0
4  | D   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   |  0  | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0
```

This is my php code, it's work to create master table,  live code at this [link](http://datacenter.pnbpbmn.com/admin.php?action=viewupload&propinsi=500)

But how to make table with inactive images to show if no value (0) and active images if month filled with value (1/2/3/4... etc)

```
<table class="table table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>UPT</th>
        <th>Jan</th>
        <th>Feb</th>
        <th>Mar</th>
        <th>Apr</th>
        <th>Mei</th>
        <th>Jun</th>
        <th>Jul</th>
        <th>Ags</th>
        <th>Sep</th>
        <th>Okt</th>
        <th>Nov</th>
        <th>Des</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?
$view = "SELECT * FROM $tb_satker WHERE kode_propinsi='$propinsi'";
$result = mysql_query($view);
$jumlah=mysql_num_rows($result);
$nomor=0;
while
($baris=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$namasatker=$baris['nama_satker'];
$kodesatker=$baris['kode_satker'];
$kodepropinsi=$baris['kode_propinsi'];
$nomor=$nomor+1;
?>
    <tr>
        <th><? echo $nomor;?></th>
        <th><? echo $namasatker;?></th>
        <th><img src="images/inactive.png"></th>
        <th><img src="images/inactive.png"></th>
        <th><img src="images/inactive.png"></th>
        <th><img src="images/inactive.png"></th>
        <th><img src="images/inactive.png"></th>
        <th><img src="images/inactive.png"></th>
        <th><img src="images/inactive.png"></th>
        <th><img src="images/inactive.png"></th>
        <th><img src="images/inactive.png"></th>
        <th><img src="images/inactive.png"></th>
        <th><img src="images/inactive.png"></th>
        <th><img src="images/inactive.png"></th>
<? }?>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

=================================================================================
Ok, so far this is my progress using LEFT JOIN

```
$view = "SELECT $tb_satker.kode_propinsi, $tb_satker.nama_satker, $tb_satker.kode_satker, $tb_upload.bulan
FROM $tb_satker
LEFT JOIN $tb_upload ON $tb_satker.kode_satker = $tb_upload.kode_satker
WHERE $tb_satker.kode_propinsi ='$propinsi'";
```

and this is php code to create table

```
$result = mysql_query($view);
$jumlah=mysql_num_rows($result);
            $nomor=0;
    while
            ($baris=mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
            $namasatker=$baris['nama_satker'];
            $kodepropinsi=$baris['kode_propinsi'];
            $bulanisi=$baris['bulan'];
            $nomor=$nomor+1;

?>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><? echo $nomor;?></td>
                                            <td><? echo $namasatker;?></td>
                                            <td><? if($bulanisi==1){?>1<img src="images/active.png"><? } else {?><img src="images/inactive.png">0<? }?></td>
                                            <td><? if($bulanisi==2){?>1<img src="images/active.png"><? } else {?><img src="images/inactive.png">0<? }?></td>
                                            <td><? if($bulanisi==3){?>1<img src="images/active.png"><? } else {?><img src="images/inactive.png">0<? }?></td>
                                            <td><? if($bulanisi==4){?>1<img src="images/active.png"><? } else {?><img src="images/inactive.png">0<? }?></td>
                                            <td><? if($bulanisi==5){?>1<img src="images/active.png"><? } else {?><img src="images/inactive.png">0<? }?></td>
                                            <td><? if($bulanisi==6){?>1<img src="images/active.png"><? } else {?><img src="images/inactive.png">0<? }?></td>
                                            <td><? if($bulanisi==7){?>1<img src="images/active.png"><? } else {?><img src="images/inactive.png">0<? }?></td>
                                            <td><? if($bulanisi==8){?>1<img src="images/active.png"><? } else {?><img src="images/inactive.png">0<? }?></td>
                                            <td><? if($bulanisi==9){?>1<img src="images/active.png"><? } else {?><img src="images/inactive.png">0<? }?></td>
                                            <td><? if($bulanisi==10){?>1<img src="images/active.png"><? } else {?><img src="images/inactive.png">0<? }?></td>
                                            <td><? if($bulanisi==11){?>1<img src="images/active.png"><? } else {?><img src="images/inactive.png">0<? }?></td>
                                            <td><? if($bulanisi==12){?>1<img src="images/active.png"><? } else {?><img src="images/inactive.png">0<? }?></td>


            <? }?>
                        </tr>
```

the problem is there are multi value (live link [here](http://datacenter.pnbpbmn.com/admin.php?action=viewupload&propinsi=500))
I think using array would be good answer but don't have idea to start.
any comment?

=========================================================================================

OK FIXED, with this method.

```
$view = "
SELECT 
$tb_satker.kode_propinsi, $tb_satker.nama_satker, $tb_satker.kode_satker,
max(case when tb_upload.bulan=1 then tb_upload.path else 0 end) as jan,
max(case when tb_upload.bulan=2 then tb_upload.path else 0 end) as feb, 
max(case when tb_upload.bulan=3 then tb_upload.path else 0 end) as mar,
max(case when tb_upload.bulan=4 then tb_upload.path else 0 end) as apr,
max(case when tb_upload.bulan=5 then tb_upload.path else 0 end) as mei,
max(case when tb_upload.bulan=6 then tb_upload.path else 0 end) as jun,
max(case when tb_upload.bulan=7 then tb_upload.path else 0 end) as jul,
max(case when tb_upload.bulan=8 then tb_upload.path else 0 end) as ags,
max(case when tb_upload.bulan=9 then tb_upload.path else 0 end) as sep,
max(case when tb_upload.bulan=10 then tb_upload.path else 0 end) as okt,
max(case when tb_upload.bulan=11 then tb_upload.path else 0 end) as nov,
max(case when tb_upload.bulan=12 then tb_upload.path else 0 end) as des
FROM $tb_satker
LEFT JOIN $tb_upload ON $tb_satker.kode_satker = $tb_upload.kode_satker
WHERE $tb_satker.kode_propinsi ='$propinsi'
GROUP BY kode_satker";
```

Comment: `th` is used in `thead`, in `tbody` use `td`...

Comment: yes i don't have list of month field in database, just single month

Comment: value 1 from tb_upload as it show satker A has upload data for month 1 (jan) and 2(feb), sorry if it's not answering your question

Comment: hi sorry, i've update my progress check my question

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not that hard, inside *while* circle you put these values:

```
<tr>
<td><? echo $nomor;?></td>
<td><? echo $namasatker;?></td>
<td><?php if ($baris['month'] == 1) echo '<img src="images/inactive.png">'; ?></td>
<td><?php if ($baris['month'] == 2) echo '<img src="images/inactive.png">'; ?></td>
<td><?php if ($baris['month'] == 3) echo '<img src="images/inactive.png">'; ?></td>
<td><?php if ($baris['month'] == 4) echo '<img src="images/inactive.png">'; ?></td>
...
```

but `$baris['month']` suppose to have several values for the same `$kodesatker` - see your tables above.
So you might need to accumulate the array first into say `$kode_month`, and then to compare:

```
<td><?php  if(in_array(1, $kode_month)) echo '<img src="images/inactive.png">'; ?></td>
<td><?php  if(in_array(2, $kode_month)) echo '<img src="images/inactive.png">'; ?></td>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `<th>` is used for headers, so its supposed to be specified just once (in your case, in `<thead>`). For the rest you have to use `<td>` tag.

Secondly, your select statement doesn't provide any data you need. Either create separate table which will contain data from both tables (easiest way) or use join (a bit challenging).

Example of possible join (not perfect and not sure if its completely 100% correct):

```
SELECT * FROM $tb_satker a LEFT JOIN $tb_upload b where a.kode_propinsi = b.kode_propinsi, a.name_satker = b.kode_satker
```

It should provide you lines that will contain almost everything you need. After that you need to research how to work with result and I'm leaving it for you. (Probably use **GROUP BY**?) Just run this statement in HaidiSQL or any another SQL tool and check what result it provides.

Talking about your main question. Inside your while loop you need to have 12 if statements which should in theory solve your problem.
So for example

```
<?while
($baris=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
... fetching code here ...
?>
    <tr>
        <th><? echo $nomor;?></th>
        <th><? echo $nama_satker;?></th>
        <th><? if ($jan == 0) echo '<img src="images/inactive.png">' else echo '<img src="images/active'.$jan.'.png">'; ?></th>'
        ... ^ similar to line before...
    </tr>
<? }?>
```

Also pay attention to typo(?) with positioning of closing `</tr>` tag.

Comment: using your ways but stuck with multi value, check my link http://datacenter.pnbpbmn.com/admin.php?action=viewupload&propinsi=500